# Order data frame based on another data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the following `data.frame`

corr

```
         A            B           C            D       
1   1.00000000  0.736315370  0.518221125  0.711950770  
2   0.73631537  1.000000000  0.674467201  0.867328184  
3   0.51822112  0.674467201  1.000000000  0.688871658  
4   0.71195077  0.867328184  0.688871658  1.000000000
```

and a second `data.frame`

```
data  cluster_id   sector_code
 1       1           A
 2       1           C
 3       2           B
 4       3           D
```

I would like data to be sorted by the headers of the corr `data.frame`

So the output should ultimately look like this:

```
data   cluster_id   sector_code
 1       1           A
 2       2           B
 3       1           C
 4       3           D
```

Comment: To increase your chances of getting the attention of users able to answer this question, you should [edit] it and add the applicable language tag. If this is an R question, as per [tag:dataframes]'s info, "For data.frame in R, use [tag:data.frame]".

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like you want an alphabetical rearrangement of your data.
This is what I used.

Let's say your second `data.frame` is called "D"

```
D <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,1,2,3), c("A","C","B","D"))
D <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,1,2,3), c("A","C","B","D"))
colnames(D) <- c("data","cluster_id","sector_code")
D <- with(D, D[order(D$sector_code, D$cluster_id), ])
```

I hope it's what you are looking for. If it's not you can also use this:

```
corr <- data.frame(c(1,0.73631537,0.51822112,0.71195077),c(0.736315370,1,0.51822112,                                                           0.867328184),c(0.518221125,0.674467201,1,0.688871658)
               ,c(0.711950770,0.867328184,0.688871658,1))
colnames(corr) <- c("A","B","C","D")
D <- with(D, D[order(colnames(corr), D$sector_code),])
```